# Is it possible to stream a image with recoding video at the same time in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, video, stream, camera

I am using the **Flutter-vision** package for object detection and the **camera** package. I tried recoding a video at that same time and image streaming to detect the object but the camera plugin we can use at a time only. any solution for my issue.

I am trying to CameraAwsome package but Flutter Vision only supports Camera Image for detection. I tried to find any other packages but not work for me